# Game Maker Mouse Click Through Code

Tags: game-maker

Title pretty much states it all. I was wandering if there is a way for me to simulate a mouse click using game makers coding language. This is going to be used for controller support for a GUI. I know I can make it work without it mouse click simulation, but it would be a lot easier if I could.

Comment: see function `event_perform()`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As Dmi7ry said, I was looking for the `event_perform()` function.